# Retrive Data from MongoDB using NodeJS with Mongoose with paging

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I stored hundreds of thousands of data in mongoDB. I am using NodeJS Rest api and mongoose to retrieve the data.

I used MongooseSchema.find() to get data from DB. its works fine. but the problem is i am going to display the list of data in Angular. i don't want hundreds of thousands of data at the time. Is Any way there to retrieve 50 data per request and another 50 data another request?

Example:

How to display first 20 data if the scroll down ends we have to make api call to get another set of 20 data to display?

Comment: Have you considered using `.limit()`?

Comment: i want to display all the data subsequently. for example first i have to load first 20 data if the scroll ends we have to show another set of 20 data. Is any way is there ? because user don't want all the data at the time.

Comment: What API framework are you using? Express, Hapi, etc...?

Comment: express using typescript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using [.limit()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-limit) and [.skip()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-skip) and adding paging to your API endpoint.

Limit limits the number of documents returned while skip skips a given number of documents. Usually this is used with `.sort()` to return documents in a given order such as their creation datetime.

```
Model.find(...).sort(...).limit(req.query.limit).skip(req.query.skip).exec(function(error, docs) {});
```

Example for paging:

Your app sends a request such as `GET /api/users?limit=20&skip=0` to get first 20.

Then it sends a request such as `GET /api/users?limit=20&skip=20` to get the next 20.

Comment: can you please tell me what is the purpose of skip. limit will restrict the no.of row

Comment: thanks sunknudsen. i try your approach if its work, i accept  the answer. again thanks for help. you are rocking. thanks

Comment: Always a pleasure

Comment: hi sunknudsen you solution working fine. thanks i accept your answer. keep rocking